# Unable to reach node backend from angular frontend AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and I have just setup an EC2 instance to host my MEAN stack app. I’ve added all my code and both the frontend and backend are up and running fine. The only issue is that the api calls from the frontend do not work. `curl http://localhost:3000/products` works fine from the command line and I get the correct data. But when the same link is called from the frontend I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Update:
I have changed all api calls in the frontend to `/api` and have configured nginx with…

```
location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

…for node api reverse proxy. So now the api calls are made with the link `http://<public ipv4 dns>/api/products`
However, I am still receiving the 404 not found response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front-end Angular app runs in the user's web browser, on the user's PC/laptop. All your EC2 server is doing is serving the raw JavaScript files to the browser. The browser actually runs the Angular/JavaScript code.

Thus, `localhost` from inside the Angular code is actually the PC/laptop of the person viewing your app. It is not the EC2 server. You need to change your Angular app to access your API via the EC2 server's public IP address (or public DNS name) instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have just edited my original post with an update on the changes I believe you suggested.

Comment: @Nick OK, since your latest update, what happens when you run `curl http://localhost/api/products` on the EC2 server?

Comment: When I run the curl calling localhost:3000, I get the expected response and data. When I run the curl using the public dns, I get “Error Cannot GET /products”

Comment: No, I did not say `localhost:3000`. What happens when you try to go through your Nginx proxy now? What happens when you run `curl http://localhost/api/products` from the EC2 server? (add a port number if your Nginx server is not running on port 80).

Comment: Same issue when calling `localhost/api/products`. “Cannot GET /products”

Comment: That's because it is forwarding the request to `http://localhost:3000/api/products` now, and you haven't configured your NodeJS server to accept the `/api` part of the path. As you have it configured, Nginx has no way of knowing that it needs to strip the `/api` part out of the path before forwarding it on.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Everything is working now. I just needed to add /api/ at the end of proxy pass link.

Answer (score 0):

After you get your Node.js AWS server URL, you can put it in this file in your Angular App:

my_app\src\environments\environment.prod.ts

```html
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  myServer: 'https://yourServerInTheCloudURL.com/'
};
```

Then you can use "myserver" throughout your Angular app.